# sum two columns, calculate max, min and mean value in MapReduce

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, sum

I have a sample code of mapper as the following shows, the key is UCO, the value is TaxiTotal, which should be the sum of two columns, TaxiIn and TaxiOut, how to sum the two columns?

my current solution TaxiIn + TaxiOut result in a paste number, like 333+444 = 333444, I need it to be 777， how to write the code?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys

# -- Airline Data
# Year, Month, DayofMonth, DayOfWeek, DepTime, CRSDepTime, ArrTime, CRSArrTime, UniqueCarrier, FlightNum,
# TailNum, ActualElapsedTime, CRSElapsedTime, AirTime, ArrDelay, DepDelay, Origin, Dest,         Distance, TaxiIn,
# TaxiOut, Cancelled, CancellationCode, Diverted, CarrierDelay, WeatherDelay, NASDelay, SecurityDelay, LateAircraftDelay

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    unpacked = line.split(",")
    Year, Month, DayofMonth, DayOfWeek, DepTime, CRSDepTime, ArrTime, CRSArrTime, UniqueCarrier, FlightNum, TailNum, ActualElapsedTime, CRSElapsedTime, AirTime, ArrDelay, DepDelay, Origin, Dest, Distance, TaxiIn,TaxiOut, Cancelled, CancellationCode, Diverted, CarrierDelay, WeatherDelay, NASDelay, SecurityDelay, LateAircraftDelay = line.split(",")
    UCO = "-".join([UniqueCarrier, Origin])
    results = [UCO, TaxiIn+TaxiOut]
    print("\t".join(results))
```

Comment: (Why can't you use the input builtin function?) input always returns a string, so you have to convert it to an integer before adding. `line = int(line.strip())`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it, but once I use this command, all the variables are converted to the integer, including the variables should be a string.

Comment: Modifying an iterator in a loop doesn’t do anything, but modifying the iterable will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `TaxiIn + TaxiOut` to:

```
int(TaxiIn) + int(TaxiOut)
```

See below example:

```
In [1612]: TaxiIn = '333'                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [1613]: TaxiOut = '444'                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [1614]: TaxiIn + TaxiOut                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[1614]: '333444'

In [1615]: int(TaxiIn) + int(TaxiOut)                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[1615]: 777
```

You can't have numerical sums of string, for that convert `str` to `int` or `float`.

#### your code should be:

```
results = [UCO, str(int(TaxiIn) + int(TaxiOut))]
print("\t".join(results))
```

Comment: If possible, could you help me with this question? I do lack the knowledge of programming. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603900/calculate-max-min-and-mean-value-in-mapreduce